# Is there a mobile wallet that works with a Trezor?

Tags: thin-clients, mobile, trezor

Is there a mobile wallet that support using a Trezor hardware wallet to spend coins? Is there an online resource that tracks features like this for thin-clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a mobile wallet that support using a Trezor hardware wallet to spend coins?

You first need an OTG cable and a phone that supports acting as a USB host.

Trezor has not released a mobile version of their wallet.  However they have a Wallet Manager that can be used on your mobile ([for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.trezor.app)). This allows you to manage the Trezor (but not spend money).

For wallet functionality they [recommend](https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/android.html#trezor-mycelium) using [Mycelium (Android)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycelium.wallet&hl=en) with your Trezor which has support for this. Mycellium has an [iOS client](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mycelium-bitcoin-wallet/id943912290?mt=8) but it doesn't support Trezor.

> Is there an online resource that tracks features like this for thin-clients?

The only resource that I'm aware of [is the Trezor documentation](https://doc.satoshilabs.com/trezor-user/android.html).

Trezor currently doesn't work with Apple iOS devices; it doesn't have [MFi certification](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

Comment: The current version of Mycelium doesn't work yet with Trezor if you set it up in segwit mode, i.e. when it creates addresses that start with `3`. You can track progress [here](https://github.com/mycelium-com/wallet-android/issues/379)